# Yandex Metrika API realtime visitor data

Tags: yandex, yandex-api, yandex-metrika

I am using Yandex Metrika API to display analytics data in my webpage instead of Yandex Metrika page.

I have created all necesary data visualizations, but I can't figure out how to display currently on page. Like, page visits or users. In [Yandex Reporting Api](https://tech.yandex.com/metrika/doc/api2/api_v1/intro-docpage/) I couldn't find any information about realtime data.

So far I used bytime? GET request and grouped them by minute and then retrieved page views as close as possible to current time:

**GET request:**

```
https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data/bytime?&ids=xxxxxxx&metrics=ym:s:pageviews&group=minutes&date1=#{today}&date2=#{today}&oauth_token=#{access_token}
```

All page views displays with 3-5 minute delay, so it isn't anything near realtime..

Questions:

1) Is it possible to get near realtime data (20s - 1 min) from Yandex Metrika API ? In Google Analytics there is very good Realtime Api that works very good.

2) If it is possible to get near realtime data then how it is done ? I have searched for couple days, but didn't find any usefull information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in Yandex Metrika right now, therefore it is not possible.